# Nexus 6P FPC connector

Tags: pcb, pins, fpc, smartphones

What is the importance of this metal edge of my Nexus 6P fpc connector?

I broke one of the two, would anything be affected?
Is there a name for this piece?

[image: FPC connector][image]

Comment: With no photo, I'll opine that the metal edge is called a fribbit and if you broke it your photos would be displayed upside down.

Answer (score 1):

Strain relief - connectors need mechanical strain relief so forces don't go through the pins.

Shielding, from the looks of the other side of the cable the flex cable shield is tied to this point.

If you don't have this connection, you connector might not stay in and the cable might not be properly shielded.

Comment: _"No wonder my phone wasn't working properly!"_